# The command dial on my my Nikon 5100 suddenly stopped working — what can I do?

Tags: nikon, aperture, troubleshooting

It was working fine. Just suddenly can't adjust the aperture or the f stop using the adjustment wheel while in M or A mode. In fact, the adjustment wheel doesn't work for any purpose. Basically the camera won't take a decent picture unless it's in auto.

Comment: Does the dial work for other functions?

Comment: Are you looking through the viewfinder of shooting in Live View mode?

Comment: No @mattdm yes @ Michael Clark

Comment: So, another way to put this might be "the dial stopped working", right?

Comment: @JeannaWardell "Yes" is not a particularly helpful answer to an "X or Y" question (Michael Clark's).

Comment: That is correct mattdm. It is not responding at all.

Comment: Since there was a typo using of instead of or I didn't notice that your question wasn't a yes or no question Michael Clark. My apologies. I am looking through the view finder. Thank you for the heads up Philip Kendall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, power the camera off and on.

Second, remove the lens and put it back on.

One or both of these might help. That's all I got.

Comment: Thank you Doc Pixel. Tried both. Nothing. Looks like it;s going to the shop.

Answer (score 0):

Other things to try:

- Remove battery, wait, put it back
- Reset to factory settings by pressing the two buttons with a green dot for 2 seconds (see [here](https://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/17395/~/how-to-reset-a-d-slr-to-factory-default-settings). The location of the buttons is a bit different on the D5100 but they are there too).

But most likely yes, it's going to the shop.